# Open TSDB - No such name for 'metrics': 'test'

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, opentsdb, hdp

We are always getting error:

Caused by: net.opentsdb.uid.NoSuchUniqueName: No such name for 'metrics': 'test' at net.opentsdb.uid.UniqueId$1GetIdCB.call(UniqueId.java:450) ~[tsdb-2.4.0.jar:] at net.opentsdb.uid.UniqueId$1GetIdCB.call(UniqueId.java:447) ~[tsdb-2.4.0.jar:] ... 34 common frames omitted

ERROR [AsyncHBase I/O Worker #13] UniqueId: Failed attempt #1 to assign an UID for metrics:test at step #2
org.hbase.async.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobufotobufUtil$ClassLoaderHolder

I saw that usual error on Web is if missing some of three parameters:

```
tsd.core.auto_create_metrics = true

tsd.core.auto_create_tagks = true
tsd.core.auto_create_tagvs = true
```

We are sending data to the Open TSDB.

```
echo "put test 1548838714 1 tag1=1" | nc 192.168.150.101 4243
```

Also we notice sometimes error while trying to execute echo command (if OpenTSDB is being run using the build/tsdb tsd and not through the /etc/init.d/opentsdb (by using the command service opentsdb start ):

This is configuration file:

```
# --------- NETWORK ----------
# The TCP port TSD should use for communications
# *** REQUIRED ***
tsd.network.port = 4243

# The IPv4 network address to bind to, defaults to all addresses
# tsd.network.bind = 0.0.0.0

# Enables Nagel's algorithm to reduce the number of packets sent over the
# network, default is True
#tsd.network.tcpnodelay = true

# Determines whether or not to send keepalive packets to peers, default
# is True
#tsd.network.keepalive = true

# Determines if the same socket should be used for new connections, default
# is True
#tsd.network.reuseaddress = true

# Number of worker threads dedicated to Netty, defaults to # of CPUs * 2
#tsd.network.worker_threads = 8

# Whether or not to use NIO or tradditional blocking IO, defaults to True
#tsd.network.async_io = true

# ----------- HTTP -----------
# The location of static files for the HTTP GUI interface.
# *** REQUIRED ***
tsd.http.staticroot = /opt/opentsdb-2.4.0/build/staticroot/

# Where TSD should write it's cache files to
# *** REQUIRED ***
tsd.http.cachedir = /opt/opentsdb-2.4.0/build/CACHE

# --------- CORE ----------
# Whether or not to automatically create UIDs for new metric types, default
# is False
tsd.core.auto_create_metrics = true

# --------- STORAGE ----------
# Whether or not to enable data compaction in HBase, default is True
#tsd.storage.enable_compaction = true

# How often, in milliseconds, to flush the data point queue to storage,
# default is 1,000
# tsd.storage.flush_interval = 1000

# Name of the HBase table where data points are stored, default is "tsdb"
tsd.storage.hbase.data_table = tsdb

# Name of the HBase table where UID information is stored, default is "tsdb-uid"
tsd.storage.hbase.uid_table = tsdb-uid

# Path under which the znode for the -ROOT- region is located, default is "/hbase"
tsd.storage.hbase.zk_basedir = /hbase-unsecure

# A comma separated list of Zookeeper hosts to connect to, with or without
# port specifiers, default is "localhost"
#tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorum = localhost
tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorum = namenode1.local,namenode2.local


tsd.http.request.enable_chunked = true
tsd.http.request.max_chunk = 16000


tsd.storage.fix_duplicates = true


tsd.storage.max_tags = 45

tsd.storage.uid.width.metric = 4
tsd.storage.uid.width.tagk = 4
tsd.storage.uid.width.tagv = 4


tsd.core.uid.random_metrics = true

tsd.core.auto_create_tagks = true
tsd.core.auto_create_tagvs = true
```

Comment: I understand that you do not have access to any metric, not only to test metric?

Comment: Hi @thedbogh yes. I am not able to create any metric

Comment: OpenTSDB is up and running, we can access it but we cannot PUT any metric although all the configuration is set properly in opentsdb.conf file. We are using /hbase-unsecure path which exists on all servers (not /hbase) Whatever you can do to help will be very appreciate. We are really stuck with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to collect metrics from HBase or something else?

Comment: I want to write data into OpenTSDB over the HBASE. I am collecting metrics (metric name and values by using the SNMP protocol). But currently I am just trying to make thi sone command to work (to sucessfully put data into TSDB): echo "put test 1548838714 1 tag1=1" | nc 192.168.150.101 4243  We can chat if it more convenient. Please tell me if you have any advice if you succeeded to resolve this one

Comment: I did not have this type of issue when using the OpenTSDB this is the first time, so I am really not sure why now we cannot make it work. Please tell me if you would like to chat if is more convinient for you

Comment: Are you sure metrics are added to OpenTSDB in the correct way? I recommend to use Tcollector if it meets your requirements. Furthermore, do you have automatically generated tables `["tsdb", "tsdb-meta", "tsdb-tree", "tsdb-uid"]` in HBase?

Comment: Yes metrics are added to OpenTSDB in correct way. Tables are successfully added. If I  try to invoke some other HBASE then put command is successful. I think that some issue is with permissions or configuration but I am not sure where is the issue.

Comment: Did you check the opentsdb, hbase, zookeeper and hadoop logs? Make sure there are no errors, check the logs of each node. Also make sure yarn works properly.